FastAPI: How can query parameters support a second name such as alias?
@app.get("/test")
async def test(order: str = Query(min_length=10), 
               quantity: int):
    return q

Can FastAPI's Query Parameter support a second name, e.g., only first character of name or alias name, e.g. qty?
http://zzzz/test?o=1234567890&q=20

I'm not sure what you're asking, are you asking whether you can name your parameters o and q instead of order  and quantity, whether you can have one name in your code and one in the argument, or whether you can support both order and o as valid parameters in the URL? 1) Just change the names 2) Use aliasing support: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/?h=alias#alias-parameters 3) You'll probably have to use a dependency that has both parameters and then a bit of logic with or between the values.

Alias parameters feature is fit own case.  thanks.

In addition to the link provided in the banner above, this answer might also prove helpful.
